# No overload matches this call and Types of parameters '__0' and 'props' are incompatible when passing custom params to library function on typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, parameters

I am using the react-toast-notifications to build my system and I had the need to create a parameter where I could pass the title of the toast notification, because of that now I have an alert on my IDE where it says: `No overload matches this call. Overload 1 of 2, '(props: ToastProviderProps, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | Component<ToastProviderProps, any, any> | null', gave the following error. Type '({ children, appearance, onDismiss, title }: { children: any; appearance: string; onDismiss: any; title: string; }) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<ToastProps> | undefined'.`

When I delete the custom parameter "title" the error dissapears, this is unabling me to do npm run build. Here is my code:

index.tsx=>

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ToastProvider components={{Toast *(the error appears here)*: MyCustomToast}}>
      <App />
    </ToastProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
)
```

CustomToast.tsx =>

```
const MyCustomToast = ({children, appearance, onDismiss, title}: 
    {children: any, appearance: string, onDismiss: any, title:string}) => { return(
      <div className={toastAppearance(appearance)}>      
        <div className="toast">
          <div className="row">
            <div>
              <p style={{fontSize: "16px", fontWeight: 600}}>{toastTitle(appearance, title)}</p>
              {children}
            </div>
            <div onClick={onDismiss} style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}>
              <svg className="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                <path fill="none" d="M15.898,4.045c-0.271-0.272-0.713-0.272-0.986,0l-4.71,4.711L5.493,4.045c-0.272-0.272-0.714-0.272-0.986,0s-0.272,0.714,0,0.986l4.709,4.711l-4.71,4.711c-0.272,0.271-0.272,0.713,0,0.986c0.136,0.136,0.314,0.203,0.492,0.203c0.179,0,0.357-0.067,0.493-0.203l4.711-4.711l4.71,4.711c0.137,0.136,0.314,0.203,0.494,0.203c0.178,0,0.355-0.067,0.492-0.203c0.273-0.273,0.273-0.715,0-0.986l-4.711-4.711l4.711-4.711C16.172,4.759,16.172,4.317,15.898,4.045z"></path>
              </svg>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  )}
  
  export default MyCustomToast
```

usage of the function with parameters =>

```
ngos.length > 0 ? addToast(`${t(`WEBSITE_TEXT_YOUR_SEARCH_RETURNED`)} ${response.data.total} ${t(`WEBSITE_TEXT_RESULTS`)}`, { appearance: 'info', autoDismiss: true, title: 'Result: ' }) : addToast(`${t(`WEBSITE_TEXT_NO_NGOS_WERE_FOUND`)}`, { appearance: 'error', autoDismiss: true })
```

Answer (score 0):

To add custom properties to a library type we can just:

```
type CustomToastProps = ToastProps & { title: string };

const MyCustomToast = ({children, appearance, onDismiss, title}: CustomToastProps) => { 
      return()
}
```